# Activate/Deactivate widgets with hugo-academic in blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I tried making a new website using blogdown and I wanted to use the hugo academic theme.

To do this I went

> File >> New Project >> New Directory >> Website using blogdown

I set the name to 'TestBlog3', changed the directory to '~/Documents', changed the theme to 'gcushen/hugo-academic' and I left all other options as default. I then was following through [these instructions](https://arorarshi.rbind.io/post/2020-04-24-academic-hugo-tutorial.html) when it told me to navigate to

> content >> home

and it said that I could open any `.md` file and it should look like this

```
# About widget.
widget = "about"  # See https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/page-builder/
headless = true  # This file represents a page section.
active = true  # Activate this widget? true/false
#
```

and that I can then change `active = TRUE` to `FALSE` to stop the widget from displaying. However, when I open a `.md` file, it looks like this (this is an example of `hero.md`):

```
---
widget: hero
headless: true
weight: 10
title: Hugo Academic Theme
hero_media: hero-academic.png
cta:
  label: '**Get Started**'
  url: https://wowchemy.com/hugo-themes/
cta_alt:
  label: Ask a question
  url: https://discord.gg/z8wNYzb
cta_note:
  label: >-
    <a class="js-github-release" href="https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/releases" data-repo="wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes">Latest release<!-- V --></a><div style="text-shadow: none;"><a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes" data-icon="octicon-star" data-size="large" data-show-count="true" aria-label="Star">Star Wowchemy site builder for Hugo</a></div><div style="text-shadow: none;"><a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic" data-icon="octicon-star" data-size="large" data-show-count="true" aria-label="Star">Star the Academic template</a></div>
design:
  background:
    gradient_end: '#1976d2'
    gradient_start: '#004ba0'
    text_color_light: true
advanced:
  css_class: fullscreen
---

**The FREE, Hugo-based open source website builder and template trusted by 500,000+ sites.**

**Build anything with widgets** - from landing pages, knowledge bases, and courses to academic resumés, conferences, and tech blogs.
```

I'm very confused as this looks nothing like the tutorial and every time I try and google anything I can't seem to find the right keywords to get an answer to my question.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This is a question for the theme builder. It has nothing really to do with Hugo per se. I would assume you should just do what the directions tell you to do, i.e. set "Widget" to "false" by typing exactly what it says "active = FALSE" but this isn't a hugo question... If you need to read how markdown and front matter work - see gohugo.io. The docs are pretty good IMHO.